# Trying to play audio in AnotherTerm

Tags: android, audio, vnc, termux

I'm exploring Java with [AnotherTerm](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/repo/green_green_avk.anotherterm.redist_144.apk), using AnLinux [Debian rootfs](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EXALAB/AnLinux-Resources/master/Rootfs/Debian/armhf/debian-rootfs-armhf.tar.xz) and a [script to install IceWM](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/EXALAB/AnLinux-Resources/master/Scripts/WindowManager/Apt/IceWM/de-apt-icewm.sh) for VNC server usage in proot. I'm encountering difficulty playing audio within the proot and IceWM. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I tried...

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class AudioTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Set the parameters for the audio format
            AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 1, true, false);

            // Get a SourceDataLine that matches the specified audio format
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
            SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

            // Open the SourceDataLine and start it
            line.open(audioFormat);
            line.start();

            // Generate a simple sine wave and write it to the audio output
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                double angle = i / (audioFormat.getSampleRate() / 440.0) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
                short sample = (short) (Short.MAX_VALUE * Math.sin(angle));
                buffer[0] = (byte) (sample & 0xFF);
                buffer[1] = (byte) ((sample >> 8) & 0xFF);
                line.write(buffer, 0, 2);
            }

            // Close the line when finished
            line.drain();
            line.close();

        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No line matching interface SourceDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian is supported.
        at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getLine(AudioSystem.java:425)
        at AudioTest.main(AudioTest.java:12)
```

Also...

```
$ paplay $AUDIO_FILE_PATH
Failed to open audio file.
```

---

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.21 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.21+9-post-Debian-1deb11u1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 11.0.21+9-post-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode)

$ pulseaudio --version
pulseaudio 14.2
```

Android 10
armeabi-v7a
Not Rooted

Answer (score 0):

Discovered a solution for `pulseaudio`: the PulseAudio server is capable of streaming over TCP/UDP using various protocols.

[How to Play Sound from Termux when using Linux?](https://web.archive.org/web/20231224211825/https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205576/how-to-play-sound-from-termux-when-using-linux)

[Audio in graphical session](https://web.archive.org/web/20231224212023/https://github.com/green-green-avk/AnotherTerm/issues/31)

[Simple Protocol Player](https://web.archive.org/web/20231224211424/https://github.com/kaytat/SimpleProtocolPlayer)

However, I'm perplexed about the recurring exception I encounter when playing an audio file in Java.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).